# Trouble sorting database in nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm having trouble sorting my database from last to first. This is what I have:

Index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongo = require("mongodb");
var db = require("monk")("localhost/nodeblog");

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var db = req.db;
  var posts = db.get('posts');

  posts.find({},{}, function(err, posts){
    res.render("index", {posts: posts})
  }).sort({_id: -1}).exec(function(err, docs){
    if(err) throw err
    console.log(docs)
  })

});
```

Index.ejs

```
<% include ./layout/header %>

<% posts.forEach(function(x) { %>
    <h1 class="ui header"><a href="/post/show/<%= x._id %>"><%= x.title %></a>
    <div class="sub header">Posted in <%= x.categories %> by <%=x.author%> on <%= moment(x.date).format("MM-DD-YYYY")%></div>
</h1>
<h4 clas="ui header">
<%= x.body %>
</h4>
<div class="ui teal button"><a href="/post/show/<%= x._id %>"> Read More </a></div>
```

But I get an error!

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the error is, but it looks like you have some logic in the wrong place.

Give this a try....

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongo = require("mongodb");
var db = require("monk")("localhost/nodeblog");

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var db = req.db;
  var posts = db.get('posts');

  posts.find({}).sort({_id: -1}).exec(function(err, docs){
    if(err) throw err
    console.log(docs)
    res.render("index", {posts: docs})
  })

});
```

Comment: This is the error I got: https://i.imgur.com/ntQy0cO.png when I added your code.

"Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "/Web Apps/12/Blog/nodeblog/views""

I'm using ejs as my template render.

Comment: Did the code I give throw that error?    Looks like the error is happening on line 95.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. On lane 95 all I have is the render error page. This is my app.js: http://pastebin.com/CAQRrE0Q

Comment: No worries.   That's your error middleware acting as a catch all for any exceptions.   On line 94, insert `console.log(err)` to see what the error is, or add a error view to your views folder.   Is this happening with the revised code I provided or your code?